# Moment.js displayed to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

The data for moment.js doesn't show up at all, I've tried everything from innerHTML to appending to the page. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks

```
<body>
     <header class="jumbotron">
     <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
     <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
  <div id="currentDay"></div>
     </header>



  var nMoment = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  var display = $('currentDay')
  display.innerHTML = nowMoment;
  console.log(display);
  console.log(nowMoment)
```

There is no error message, it just doesn't display to the DOM

Comment: I saw your code use var display = $('currentDay'). It should var display = $('#currentDay');

Comment: "*there is no error message*" - maybe not, but `console.log($("nohashid"))` will give 0 length and `console.log(nowMoment)` will give `undefined` - both of these need fixing *before* worrying about it "display to the DOM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few issues in your code:

1. You did not specify the id symbol (`#`) in the selector.
2. You do not have *nowMoment* in your code, it should be *nMoment*.
3. Using jQuery, you should use `text()` to modify the the text content of the *div* element.

Try the following way:

```js
var nMoment = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
var display = $('#currentDay');
display.text(nMoment);
//console.log(display);
console.log(nMoment)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<header class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
  <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
  <div id="currentDay"></div>
</header>
```